# What is causing the type error in my code?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, express, body-parser

I am trying to console.log the input in this sign up form but every time i fill the details and the submit the form then it shows the following error
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'fName')

Kindly let me know the error in my code.

```
<form action="/" method="POST">
    <img class="mb-4" src="images/mail.jpg" alt="" width="72" height="57">
    <h1 class="h3 mb-3 fw-normal">Signup the Newsletter</h1>
    <div class="form-floating">
      <input type="text" name="fName" class="form-control top"  placeholder="First Name">
 </div>
    <div class="form-floating">
      <input type="text" name="lName" class="form-control middle"  placeholder="Last Name">
    </div>
    <div class="form-floating">
      <input type="email" name="email" class="form-control bottom"  placeholder="name@example.com">

    </div>


    <button class="w-100 btn btn-lg btn-primary" type="submit">Sign in</button>
    <p class="mt-5 mb-3 text-muted">Follow me</p>
  </form>
```

````
// const https = require("https");

const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const request = require("request");

const app = express();
app.use(express.static("public"));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended:true}));


app.get("/", function(req, res) {
  res.sendFile(__dirname + "/signup.html");
});

app.post("/", function(res, req){
  var firstName = req.body.fName;
  var middleName = req.body.lName;
  var eMail = req.body.email;

  console.log(firstName, middleName, eMail);
});

app.listen(3000, function() {
  console.log("Server is running on Port 3000");
}); ```
````

Answer (score 2):

I found these errors in your code, check them and it will work fine.

`app.use("/public", express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));` // use this for defining your public folder (and don't forget to import path module above).

```
app.post("/", function(req, res, next){
 var firstName = req.body.fName;
 var middleName = req.body.lName;
 var eMail = req.body.email;
 console.log(firstName, middleName, eMail);
});
```

Here as you can see in the callback function we get three parameters first will be the `request` object, second will be the `response` object and third is optional `next` object.
But in your case you are reading it from response object but it should be from request.

Thanks